# Does Fatou's lemma hold for the sequence $f_{n}(x) = e^{-2x}-ne^{-nx}$ on $E=(0, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Does Fatou's lemma hold for the sequence $f_{n}(x) = e^{-2x}-ne^{-nx}$ on $E=(0, \infty)$?

I'm thinking it does not because the sequence of functions is not nonnegative. The sequence does however converge pointwise to $f(x)=e^{-2x}$ on $(0, \infty)$. To prove it does not hold requires that I prove $$\int_{E} f(x) > \liminf \int_{E} f_{n}.$$

I can do "standard" integration to see that the LHS is $1/2$ but the RHS is $-1/2$, so the inequality is true. However, I need to be doing Lebesgue integration and I'm not sure how can I show that they're both the same in this example and equal.

Comment: Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ are also Lebesgue integrable on on $[a,b]$ and the value of the integral is the same for both.

Comment: @geetha290krm I guess what's confusing to me is that I thought $f$ needs to be defined on a closed and bounded interval for the two integrals to be the same and here $E$ is not bounded.

Comment: You can always take limits (for both types of integrals ) to go from $[\frac 1 n ,n]$ to $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see. Your idea is to write $E$ as the union of $[1/n, n]$ and then use $\int_{\cup[1/n, n]} f = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[1/n, n]}f$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm I'm having a little trouble evaluating the RHS. Using Riemann integration, $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{2x}-ne^{-nx}\: dx = -1/2$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[1/n, n]} e^{-2x}-ne^{-nx} \;dx = (1/2)-(1/e)$?

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty} ne^{-nx}dx=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y}dy=1$ by the substitution $y=nx$. How did you get $\frac 1 e$?

Comment: @geetha290krm I did get $1$ for that integral, but I'm talking about the integral that you need to evaluate on the RHS. You can see for yourself here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+%28integral+%28e%5E%7B-2x%7D+-+ne%5E%7B-nx%7D%29+from+1%2Fn+to+n%29+as+n+goes+to+infinity

Comment: @geetha290krm: Nevermind, I figured what I was doing wrong. Using the variable $k$ for the limit instead gets us the right answer.